# Call Api with body as multipart/form-data

Tags: c#, api, multipartform-data

i have to call an Api that get a  body as multipart/form-data with 4 parameters.
I have done so:`

```
MultipartFormDataContent body = new MultipartFormDataContent();
body.Add(new StringContent("item_id"), value);
body.Add(new StringContent("ateco_code"), value);
body.Add(new StringContent("province"), value);
body.Add(new StringContent("csv_data"), value);
```

And then transform the body into stream because Api want a stream (System.IO.Stream body)
var bodystream = body.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;

It's correct? Because i get always BAD REQUEST

Comment: HTTP has no streams, so no HTTP API requires a .NET Stream object. It's HttpClient's job to write the content to the request stream. Have you tried just using that Content object? If the API expects a file, where is the file?

Comment: I not have a file to send. What mean Have you tried just using that Content object, can make me an example?

Comment: `await client.PostAsync(url,body);` Have you tried that? How do you make the request?

Comment: Yes but the problem is the request, i not know how do the correct request

Comment: That's how you send the request. [HttpClient's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-6.0) shows how to specify extra headers. You don't have to manually manage streams, that's HttpClient's job. You haven't posted any *actual* code though. Do you *really* want to use the same value for  `item_id`, `ateo_code` and all other parts? Does the remote service require different parts or different *fields*? What does the service's doc actually say?

Comment: To send a FORM POST you should use the [FormUrlEncodedContent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.formurlencodedcontent?view=net-6.0) class